# Creating a GUI for a command-line utility using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nstask

I'm looking for a way to create a GUI (using Cocoa) to make a command-line utility more accessible to some of my colleagues. If you use NSTask to execute/start the utility, can you then simply use another NSTask to execute the next command (using the utility launched in the previous step)? Does it use the same session, in other words? I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been awhile but IIRC then yes the NSTask does execute in the same session. I know for certain that it does capture the apps entire stdio unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I have it figured out now!